# Has anyone been able to get the aweber plugin to work

Tags: plugins, widgets

Aweber has a new api https://labs.aweber.com/ and based on that they have written a plugin: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/aweber-web-form-widget/ for WordPress that adds a widget. In my testing ( latest WordPress, default theme, PHP version 5 ) I have not been able to get this plugin to work.

I et through authentication ok, but am unable to pull anything through the API to make the widget work.

Can anyone else verify whether or not the plugin is working for them.

Also, has anyone else built anything that works with the API yet?

Comment: This might be a better question for the AWeber folks.  They very well might have a bug and might be better able to diagnose it if you communicate with them directly.

Comment: I probably should have said this in the original Q. I am in communication with them. First they blamed the theme and wordpress version, when I switched to TwentyTen and updated to the latest (from 3.0.1 to 3.0.2) and the problem persisted they said it was a known bug, they then turned around 2 days later and have said "everyone else who is using it says it works fine, your the only one with problems". So I was curious to know if in fact everyone else is really having no problems. I can't get this to work on a vanilla install on 5 different servers and think maybe Aweber has lost the plot

Comment: Voting to close. While I sympathize with you regarding the customer "service", this is something better discussed by other means (chat, forums, etc.)

Comment: Vote to close? That makes no sense!I am not asking anyone to discuss aweber, I am simply asking if anyone has in fact gotten it to work. The lack of answers is itself an answer I suppose. This is a plugin for WordPress that I cannot get to work and that I was wondering if anyone else had. Are we not to discuss plugins here anymore? Voting to close is a particularly amusing respose in light of recent attempts to encourage plugin authors to provide support here.

Answer (score 1):

It's working fine in my blog sidebar although I needed to carefully size the form correctly at aweber and add a background colour to the widget to make it display well. It's not the easiest but it works.

Answer (score 0):

try uninstalling the plugin after you update wordpress to latest and re-install it again.

somehow the "start over everything" startegy